# Python formatting

Tags: python, format

I tried the following code but failed to print out any results. An syntax error occured.

```
mydict = {'carl':40,
          'alan':2,
          'bob':1,
          'danny':3}

for key in sorted(mydict):
    print "%s: %s" % (key, mydict[key])
```

Comment: In the future, be sure to actually include the error message in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put parenthesis in your `print`.  Change `print "%s: %s" % (key, mydict[key])` into `print("%s: %s" % (key, mydict[key]))` (I think that you are using python3)